# Disable Gravatars in WordPress

Tags: plugins, avatar, gravatar

I have found this code for disable gravatar on email but it not work on 100% why? Because it replace online image but the image always open with gravatar domanin..

```
function __default_local_avatar()
{
    // this assumes default_avatar.png is in wp-content/themes/active-theme/images
    return get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/default_avatar.png';
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_avatar_default', '__default_local_avatar' );
```

How to remove request from gravatar without delete avatar?

Comment: You can change it from Discussion settings.

Comment: no, discussion settings --> only disable or change image

Comment: open wp-includes/pluggable.php and remove gravatar.com domain, replace url with local avatar!! SIMPLE VERY SIMPLE

Comment: That code does not disable gravatar, it just sets a custom default image.

Comment: So is this not possible then?